# "No such file or directory" immediately after creating it

Tags: linux, docker, unix, ghost-blog

### Some background...

I am trying to build a Docker image for a Ghost blog. I am just adding one module: a Storage Adapter so that images are hosted on S3 instead of local filesystem (default setting).

In the README of the [storage adapter plugin](https://github.com/colinmeinke/ghost-storage-adapter-s3), the installation instructions are to copy the module into the working directory of the app:

```
npm install ghost-storage-adapter-s3
mkdir -p ./content/adapters/storage
cp -r ./node_modules/ghost-storage-adapter-s3 ./content/adapters/storage/s3
```

and that works -- but only **inside** of the container. I want to run these steps in the Docker build, so that if my container restarts, I don't lose these changes.

### The issue

In my Dockerfile, I have:

```
FROM ghost:3
RUN npm install ghost-storage-adapter-s3
RUN mkdir -p ./content/adapters/storage
RUN cp -r ./node_modules/ghost-storage-adapter-s3/ ./content/adapters/storage/s3
```

and it throws this error: `cp: cannot create directory './content/adapters/storage/s3': No such file or directory`

When I take a step back and try to create one directory at a time and validate it was created, i.e.

```
RUN ls ./content
RUN mkdir ./content/adapters
RUN ls ./content/adapters
```

I get this error:

```
Step 8/10 : RUN ls ./content/adapters
 ---> Running in c55848f39bb4
ls: cannot access './content/adapters': No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c ls ./content/adapters' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

How is possible that there is "no such directory" after I just created it?

I tried setting chmod permissions when I create the folder `mkdir -m 777 ./content/adapters`, and updating owner to my current user (root): `RUN chown -R root ./content` but no effect.

I was able to get it to at least build by changing the `./` directory prefixes, but that puts /content in the app root which is not where they need to be. When I specify the full path `/var/lib/ghost/content/adapters/storage` I get the same error. It seems to be a permissions thing but I don't know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to use `COPY`/`ADD` instructions to copy from the host to the container.

Comment: @funnydman I don't want my docker image to be dependent upon the host container, it should be able to build everything it needs on its own

Answer (score 2):

That's the typical symptom of the base image [declaring a VOLUME](https://github.com/docker-library/ghost/blob/aeed5c9122e22c71f321c36f11f8794b3915dce5/3/debian/Dockerfile#L94) for its install directory.  You can't create a derived image that has any additional content in that directory, plugins or otherwise.

If you're not trying to do this repeatably, then you could launch a copy of the image with some local storage attached, run that installation once, and then use the populated data directory for real.

```sh
docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/ghost:/var/lib/ghost/content ghost:3 bash
npm install ghost-storage-adapter-s3
mkdir -p ./content/adapters/storage
cp -r ./node_modules/ghost-storage-adapter-s3/ ./content/adapters/storage/s3
exit

docker run -d -p 2368:2368 -v $PWD/ghost:/var/lib/ghost/content ghost:3
```

If you want to do this repeatedly then (as @Wonkledge notes in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59916895/10008173)) you can use an entrypoint script to copy this in at startup, after any volumes have been attached to the container.  Note that the image [already declares its own entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/ghost/blob/aeed5c9122e22c71f321c36f11f8794b3915dce5/3/debian/Dockerfile#L97) so you need to wrap that.  Your Dockerfile might look like

```sh
FROM ghost:3
RUN npm install ghost-storage-adapter-s3
COPY entrypoint-wrapper.sh /usr/local/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint-wrapper.sh"]
```

and the wrapper script

```sh
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p ./content/adapters/storage
cp -r ./node_modules/ghost-storage-adapter-s3/ ./content/adapters/storage/s3
exec docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"
```

Notice how these two lines that affect the `content` directory tree move from inside the Dockerfile to after the container starts.

(If an image declares a VOLUME, then Docker mounts a volume on that directory every time it creates a container, whether there's a `docker run -v` option or not.  During the Dockerfile, you get a new anonymous volume for every RUN line, which is why changes to that directory tree don't actually persist in the image.)

Comment: The first way doesn't seem to make sense for production use. I can't get the second way to work... when I run `docker run -it --name ghost -e url=http://localhost:2368 -p 2368:2368 myimage:tag` there is no output from Docker, it's as if it is not running the entrypoint script. Here is my repo if anyone is able to take a look https://github.com/markjackson02/ghost-blog-with-s3-adapter Thank you very much

Comment: Is the `entrypoint-wrapper.sh` script executable?  Since it's under your control you can add things like extra `echo` statements to see if and how it's running.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it's working inside your container, you can write an script bash as entrypoint which handle that for you. So everytime your container restart, you do not lose your changes.